# Very slow transfer to Seagate Central

Tags: performance, nas

Copying a single file of 341GB from Seagate Expansion via USB3 on laptop, then Ethernet to router and Seagate Central. Seeing less than 4MBs. Started the job 18 hours ago, another 5 to go!

It only took 2-3 hours to write the file from my Win10 laptop to Seagate Expansion, so the problem does seem to lie with the Central NAS.

Any thoughts on what might cause this?

Comment: If you are not gigabit all the way through, the max transfer is realistically going to be about 11MB/s (88-95 Mbit). If the Central is pegging CPU or you have A/V software with "real-time mode" enabled, I can see it maybe dropping to 4MB/s (which is about 32Mbit). There is also overhead from HDD->USB->Laptop->Ethernet/Central. HTTPS protocol can add a lot of overhead also (?)

Comment: Thanks York. No, I'm not gigabit all the way. Maybe Kaspersky is in the way. I'll try disconnecting from the web and disabling Kaspersky.